# google login auth2.0 passport is not working

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-authentication, google-signin

hello guys i am trying to login using google auth2.0 strategy in passport, all thing going well but when i click on my google profile, i got a error saying that

> the connection for this site is not secure and local host is given invalid response

you can check below the picture of the error page

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zcvq.jpg)

### MY APP.JS CODE

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const _ = require("lodash");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "this is my secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDatabase");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "https://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
      userProfileURL:"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      console.log(profile);
      User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        return cb(err, user);
      });
    }
  )
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home");
});

app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] })
);

app.get(
  "/auth/google/secrets",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("/secrets");
  }
);

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("register");
});

app.get("/secrets", (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render("secrets");
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.register(
    { username: req.body.username },
    req.body.password,
    (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/register");
      } else {
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
          res.redirect("/secrets");
        });
      }
    }
  );
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
  });

  req.login(user, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
        res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000, (req, res) => {
  console.log("server is running fine");
});
```

### NPM MODULE THAT I AM USING

```js
{
  "name": "mongoosetuts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongodb": "^4.1.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.12",
    "mongoose-encryption": "^2.1.2",
    "mongoose-findorcreate": "^3.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.5.2",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

### MY REGISTER PAGE CODE

```html
<%- include('partials/header') %>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h1>Register</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">

          <!-- Makes POST request to /register route -->
          <form action="/register" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Register</button>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card social-block">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a class="btn btn-block" href="/auth/google" role="button">
            <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
            Sign Up with Google
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 

  </div>
</div>

<%- include('partials/header') %>
```

### MY LOGIN PAGE CODE

```html
<%- include('partials/header') %>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <h1>Login</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">

          <!-- Makes POST request to /login route -->
          <form action="/login" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Login</button>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a class="btn btn-block" href="/auth/google" role="button">
            <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
            Sign In with Google
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 

  </div>
</div>

<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

### MY SECRET PAGE CODE

```html
<%- include('partials/header') %>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <i class="fas fa-key fa-6x"></i>
    <h1 class="display-3">You've Discovered My Secret!</h1>
    <p class="secret-text">Jack Bauer is my hero.</p>
    <hr>
    
    <a class="btn btn-light btn-lg" href="/logout" role="button">Log Out</a>
    <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="/submit" role="button">Submit a Secret</a>
  </div>
</div>

<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

### MY HOME PAGE CODE

```html
<%- include('partials/header') %>


<div class="jumbotron centered">
  <div class="container">
    <i class="fas fa-key fa-6x"></i>
    <h1 class="display-3">Secrets</h1>
    <p class="lead">Don't keep your secrets, share them anonymously!</p>
    <hr>
    <a class="btn btn-light btn-lg" href="/register" role="button">Register</a>
    <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="/login" role="button">Login</a>

  </div>
</div>

<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

### MY EJS HEADER CODE

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Secrets</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
```

### MY FOOTER EJS CODE

```html
</body>
</html>
```

> guys please help i already check all error your help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution? If not, I'd try http://localhost... instead of https://localhost... since you need a working self-signed certificate for using https with localhost for communicating e.g. with google. Make sure you have http in your google API settings too.